# NSSound strange bug

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssound

This code plays the sound:

```
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/alex/test.ogg"
                                            byReference:NO];
[sound play];
```

This code does not:

```
NSData *song = [testingResultsData objectAtIndex:0];
[song writeToFile:@"/Users/alex/test.ogg" atomically:YES];
NSSound *sound = [[NSSound alloc] initWithData:song];
[sound play];
```

It is the same content in both cases; the only difference is whether it is taken from a file on disk or directly from `NSData`.

Comment: Please some more information. What does not play fine? And what is _testingResultsData_?

Comment: How exactly did you check whether `song` does contain the same bytes as /Users/alex/test.ogg?

Comment: as u seen, i'm save NSData song at disk. Later, if i using it as initOfContensOfFile, everything work fine/

Comment: What is song? Almost likely it's not valid, thus why you get the error.